# django rest swagger allowMultiple parameters as arrays

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to create filter in django rest swagger YAML, with multiple value in parameters. But it doesn't work. It still return as string separate by commas.

For example, I need to query just like `?name=jack&name=jill` but I'm not sure how to performe this. I always got result `?name=jack,jill` not `?name=jack&name=jill`.

This is related to github issue https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger/issues/312.